# Need to customize the upload field in openerp?

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7

I need to remove the save as button from openerp upload field. Can someone please help me.

[image]

Comment: Nice votering you got there.  Shame if something happens to it.

Answer (score 1):

First go below path.

```
7.0-web => addons => web => static => src => xml => base.xml
```

Now find `class="oe_form_binary_file_save_data"` and comment that whole `<a> tag.`

```
<!--a class="oe_form_binary_file_save_data">
    <button class="oe_button oe_form_binary_file_save" type="button" title="Save As">
        <img t-att-src='_s + "/web/static/src/img/icons/gtk-save.png"'/>
        <span>Save As</span>
    </button>
</a-->
```

After refresh browser and it will remove a Save As button.